# Why does LQP mark reviews "not reviewable" immediately after I skip without any invalidating event?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I skipped several posts <sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/14767577), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/14766904), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/14767578), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/14767574), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/14767731)</sup> while reviewing LQP just now. Then I wanted to go back to one of them to resolve it after all, but, although it had only been a few minutes and nothing had happened to the post and the review didn't show up in the timeline as invalidated, I got "This item is not reviewable". The same thing happened with the others when I checked them (once, after no more than five seconds!), and in fact other reviewers have in some cases kept reviewing them. Is there some new measure taken that makes <kbd>Skip</kbd> permanent? (It's never been permanent before in my experience reviewing, and the ability to change one's mind about whether a post is possible to review is very handy at times.)

[This isn't unique to SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/48504), unfortunately.

Comment: are they after two hours still not reviewable for you?

Comment: @rene: Nope! (Two are complete, and so don't show it, but the others have the same message.)

Comment: I think that it is against avoiding audits. It looks like a feature to me. It's different on different queues.

Comment: @xenteros: But, it doesn't do a thing to avoid audits. Skipping won't let you see whether it was an audit unless you come back to it after someone else passed it… in which case it won't count. And if you skip an audit you can't handle, then decide to come back and try again, I don't see what the problem is. Either you pass it by putting enough attention/effort into it (good, audit success) or you fail it by pushing yourself too hard (good, audit success).

Comment: The [Meta.SE version of this bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291299/unable-to-later-review-skipped-low-quality-posts-reviews-which-is-normally-allo) was just marked as under review today.

Answer (score 8):

This was [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) [this last July](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367908/377214):

> This will be fixed in the next build.
>
> Each queue has a general filter to exclude non-skip reviewed tasks when picking new ones, but a handful of queues have cross-validation on post ID. The apparent thought is that we don't want the reviewer handling the same post in multiple queues. (For example, the same post could end up in First Posts and Late Answers.) Unfortunately, this additional exclusion logic treated skipped tasks as reviews and prevented them from being returned to.